# The nth term of a sequence is $na + b$. Prove that the sequence is an A. P. with common difference $a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

attempt: if the common difference is $a$, then the AP will be $[(na+b),a+(na+b),\dots)$; hence, proved.

My math textbook doesn't have an answer, so I don't know if am I wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site. I've added math markup to your question.

Comment: You didn't prove the required statement -- you (more or less) proved its [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) instead. Starting with what you need to prove as if it's the assumption is logically wrong.

Comment: Will I be right if I'm able to prove *a* as the common difference; since any sequence with a common difference is an A.P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we should imagine $n$ taking on the values $1,2,3,4,\dots$.

So the first term (when $n=1$) is $na+b = 1a+b = a+b$.

The second term (when $n=2$) is $na+b=2a+b$.

The third term (when $n=3$) is $na+b=3a+b$, etc.

So the sequence will be $[a+b, 2a+b, 3a+b, 4a+b, \dots]$.

> attempt: if the common difference is $a$ ...

You have to be careful here.  "The common difference is $a$" is the thing you're trying to prove.  Ideally your argument should go:

- "Assume the $n$-th term of a sequence is $an+b$.
- Then [blah blah reasons blah].
- And [blah blah more steps].
- And that means the sequence is an AP with common difference is $a$".

Watch out!  You have to be careful if you start out assuming the thing you're trying to prove. You **never** start with the thing you're trying to prove and work back to the assumptions (it's like driving the wrong way along a one-way-street) UNLESS it happens that the steps are all reversible.

**OK, that's what you shouldn't do. What should you do?**

Well, we can write out the first few terms of the sequence, when $n=1,2,3,4$ say. (see at the top for how we get this).  That tells us the sequence is $$[a+b, 2a+b, 3a+b, 4a+b, \dots]$$

What next?  One of the things we have to do is prove the common difference is $a$.  Let's try looking at some of the differences.

The difference between the first and second terms is $(2a+b)-(a+b) = 2a+b-a-b = a$. Hey, that's good!

The difference between the second and third terms is $(3a+b)-(2a+b) = 3a+b-2a-b = a$.

The difference between the third and fourth terms is $(4a+b)-(3a+b) = 4a+b-3a-b = a$.

At this point you can **see** this pattern will continue.

You could write your proof as:

1. The sequence is $[a+b, 2a+b, 3a+b, 4a+b, \dots]$
2. The difference between the first and second terms is (2a+b)-(a+b) = $a$
3. The difference between the second and third terms is (3a+b)-(2a+b) = $a$
4. The difference between the third and fourth terms is (4a+b)-(3a+b) = $a$
5. Therefore the sequence is an AP with common difference $a$.

But that last line is **not good**.  You can see a pattern here, but the teacher can't see inside your head to see the pattern you see.  Let's at least **say** there's a pattern.

5. This pattern obviously continues, and the difference between any term and the next term will be $a$.
6. Therefore the sequence is an AP with common difference $a$.

That's better. But we can **really** nail the argument by spelling out **why** that difference is always $a$.  The idea here is to pull that general pattern out of the examples.

5. The difference between the $k$th and $(k+1)$th terms is $(k+1)a+b - (ka+b) = ka + a + b - ka - b = a$.
6. Therefore the sequence is an AP with common difference $a$.

If you're not so comfortable with algebra, that new line $5$ is hard to understand!  Here's what's going on in detail.  We want to talk about what happens with **any** term and the next term.  So we invent a name for the number of the term we want to talk about, say $k$. Then the $k$th term (when $n=k$) is $na+b = ka+b$. The next number along from $k$ is $k+1$, so the term following the $k$-th term is the $(k+1)$th term (when $n=k+1$) which is $na+b=(k+1)a+b$.

In fact, with those last lines $5$ and $6$, you can don't really need the earlier lines!  Line $5$ is very classy - it says the difference between **any** term and the next one is $a$, which is enough by itself to show the sequence is an AP with common difference $a$.  But it's nice to keep lines $1-4$ because it shows the pattern clearly before taking the step with lots of algebra.